# Building a datastructure in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

I am trying to construct a DTO object to ferry the data from data layer to view layer.

The data is as follows:

- There are 7 days(dates can be used as a key in Map or any other datastructure)
- The individual dates will contain multiple records.
- Each record contains contact details obtained from multiple tables.
- One record needs to be constructed from 3 rows in the result table. ie:
  A record may return three rows with same values for all columns except for the user details; which contains details like id,name and designation.

When I display, I need to show their name as Manager and assistant manager in the same row.

```
Data Layer
T01      25/12/2012   ABC             XYZ  Manager
T01      25/12/2012   ABC             IJK  Asst.manager
Display:
Date 1
TaskID Taskdeadline  TaskGivenBy  Task assigned to Manager Task Assigned toAsst.Manager 
T01      25/12/2012   ABC             XYZ                       IJK
T02       1/1/2013    BCE             WUV                       MNO
```

Solution I tried:

```
Map<Date,Map<Position,Object>>
Map<25/12/2012,Map<(Manager,Object details),(Asst Manager,Object details)>
```

and then repeat it. But I guess I am storing duplicate data. I don't think this is an ideal solution

Comment: Don't expect us to write a solution for you, try something and then come here !

Comment: Can you explain your data a bit more? What are 'ABC' and 'XYZ' in the same row in the Data Layer? How is the data being aggregated in the View layer? Will there be multiple hierarchies? A assigns to B assigns to C? Or will there be more?

Comment: OK its like this.In data layer the data is fetched after joining multiple tables where a person can be a manager or an assistant manager.A job needs both Manager and assistant manager.So in data layer it will come as seperate rows but in view layer they should be merged as one row and displayed.No hierarchies other than Assistant manager reports to Manager